# Are martingales actually continuous?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, martingales

There are strong theorems like the martingale convergence theorem giving us the existence of a continuous limit for $t \rightarrow \infty$ of a martingale $(X_t).$

But I was wondering under which conditions we have $\lim_{t \rightarrow s} X_t=X_s$ almost surely for a martingale. Are there typical conditions under which this is satisfied, too?

Comment: I'm *almost sure* that don't exists general conditions. Indeed, the Wienner Process $\{W_t\}$ is a martingale with no necesarily continous paths (but, by Kolmogorov's Continuity Theorem there is a version of $\{W_t\}$ with continous paths a.e.)

Comment: Under relatively weak assumptions, martingales have càdlàg modifications; see e.g. this [question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1140106/) for a typical result. It might be tempting to just replace "right-cts." by "continuous" in the mentioned theorem and hope that this gives a continuous modification; as it was discussed [here](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/125323/what-conditions-on-a-filtration-guarantee-that-a-submartingale-has-a-continuou) this doesn't work out.